# Do static routes overide manual proxy cofiguration??

Tags: proxy

Do static routes overide manual proxy cofiguration??

I telneted into my router and ran the route command and discovered the default gateway of my router. I also ran traceroute on my computer and noticed that the first hop was the same ip as the one that was configured on my home router. If i were to configure my computer to route all intended traffic to a SOCK5 proxy, would the data still take the route that was already configured by my isp before going through the proxy that i configured, or would the traffic just go through the proxy without ever touching the preconfigured route.

Answer (score 0):

routing is an IP-level thing, it basically defines a set of rules for how to forward IP packets.

Proxy configuration is higher level.  If a client is using a proxy, eventually it will make a connection to the proxy, which will be over TCP/IP. At this point the routing kicks in, affecting how the IP packets are forwarded.

So these are orthogonal issues, although some browsers if they know they have a default gateway configured will ignore proxy settings (at least they have done so in the past) in order to get past poor configuration choices.